# Hattori-Stallings trace

Tags: rt.representation-theory, homological-algebra, noncommutative-rings, projective-modules, traces

Let $R$ be a (possibly non-commutative) unital ring and $M$ be a left $R$-module. If $M$ is finitely generated and projective, the natural map $$\iota:\mathrm{Hom}_R(M,R)\otimes_R M\to \mathrm{Hom}_R(M,M):f\otimes m \mapsto (m'\mapsto (f(m')m))$$
is an isomorphism and we can define the Hattori-Stallings trace by the composition
$$\mathrm{Tr}:\mathrm{Hom}_R(M,M)\xrightarrow{\iota^{-1}}\mathrm{Hom}_R(M,R)\otimes_R M \xrightarrow{\mathrm{ev}} R/[R,R].$$
My first question is:

(1) Does $\mathrm{Tr}([f,g])=0$ hold for any $R$-module map $f,g:M\to M$?

If $M$ is further assumed to be free, this is true since we can take a free basis and directly compute it.

---

Next, assume $M$ to be a perfect module (i.e., there exists a finite-length projective resolution $P_\bullet \to M$ with each $P_n$ being finitely generated). In this case, we can presumably define the trace of $f:M\to M$ by taking a lift $f_\bullet:P_\bullet\to P_\bullet$ and setting $$\operatorname{Tr}(f) = \sum_i(-1)^i\operatorname{Tr}(f_i).$$

My second question is:

(2) How can we prove that this is well-defined? Or, are there any references?

[This MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/7655/trace-map-attached-to-a-finite-homomorphism-of-noetherian-rings) claims that it is well-defined without any proof.

Thank you.

Comment: `\mathrm{Tr}` and `\operatorname{Tr}` don't always have the same effect, and in this case in particular the use of the former was the cause of a lack of proper horizontal spacing.

Comment: There is also a pedestrian way to do the Hattori-Stallings trace.  For a square matrix over $R$, one can define the trace as the image in $R/[R,R]$ of the sum of the diagonal entries and then the usual proof shows $Tr(AB )=Tr(BA)$ for not necessarily square matrices.  This implies in particular it doesn't depend on the basis and one can check also that it gives the same answer for free modules as you defined above.  If $P$ is a finitely generated projective, one can find a square idempotent matrix $E\in M_n(R)$ with $P$ isomorphic to the image of $E$ and with $EM_n(R)E\cong End_R(P)$.  (Ctd)

Comment: One can then show that if you take the corresponding matrix trace of an element of $EM_n(R)E$, then it gives the Hattori-Stallings trace of the endomorphism and it is independent of the choice of $E$ (again using that $Tr(AB)=Tr(BA)$ for not necessarily square matrices).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer to (1) is yes. In fact this is true more generally: for any $f: M\to N, g:N\to M$, you have $tr(fg) = tr(gf)$.

The point is that $\hom_R(M,N)\otimes \hom_R(N,M)\cong \hom_R(M,R)\otimes_R N \otimes \hom_R(N,R)\otimes_R M$ and that under this identification, composition in one direction corresponds to evaluation $N\otimes\hom_R(N,R)\to R$, and in the other direction it corresponds to $\hom_R(M,R)\otimes M \to R$.

But since you're composing and then evaluating anyways, it amounts to evaluating both, and so they are equal.

For (2), the most conceptual way is to give a definition that does *not* depend on the chosen resolution. It works the same as what you explained, but using derived hom's and tensors. Namely, for $M$ perfect, the canonical map $\mathrm{RHom}_R(M,R)\otimes^L_R M\to \mathrm{RHom}_R(M,M)$ is a quasi-isomorphism, and the former has a map $\mathrm{RHom}_R(M,R)\otimes^L_R M\to R\otimes^L_{R\otimes^L R^{op}}R$, the $H_0$ of the latter simply being $R/[R,R]$.

Combining all of these you get that $tr$ is defined on $H_0(\mathrm{RHom}_R(M,M))$, which is $\hom_R(M,M)$; but in fact it is more properly a map $\mathrm{RHom}_R(M,M)\to HH(R)$, where $HH$ is Hochschild (or maybe Shukla) homology, i.e. $R\otimes^L_{R\otimes^L R^{op}}R$.

You can then *check* that this "fancy" definition of the trace agrees with the concrete one given by a projective resolution. Alternatively, you can prove it as a theorem, namely, it follows from the *additivity of Hattori-Stallings traces*, which itself can be proved in several different ways, e.g. by proving that $HH$ is a "localizing invariant"

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! I know the definition of derived tensor, but I don't know what $R\otimes^L R^\mathrm{op}$ means. It is supposed to be a some kind of ring...  Could you explain it?

Comment: It is the derived tensor product of $R$ with $R^{op}$, over an implicit base. It turns out that this this can be made into a differential graded algebra (or more conceptually an $E_1$-ring, but they can be represented by dga's). More generally, whenever $A,B$ are two rings (or even dgas), their derived tensor product $A\otimes^L B$ has an $E_1$-ring structure/ can be represented by a dga

Comment: (if $R$ is flat over your implicit base, this is just $R\otimes R^{op}$, no deriving)